# how to block toggle class when classe is on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using several anchors and when clicking on an anchor, the class switches to **img-swap on**
If I click on another anchor, the class of that anchor switches also on **on**
What I want to achieve: if 1 anchor has already the class on **on**, all other anchors must be blocked to switch on **on**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 $('a.img-swap').click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('on');
 }); 
});
```

Is this possible to do a check in javascript when a class is on **on** and if so, block the other anchors to switch from class?

Comment: you can check the with `hasClass` https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/ ..

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('a.img-swap').click(function () {
        if(!$("a.img-swap").hasClass("on"))
            $(this).toggleClass('on');
    });
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I would just bind handler to be fired only once:</strike>

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 $('a.img-swap').one('click', function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('on');
 }); 
});
```

Now if you want state `on` to be switchable, i'd use instead:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 $('a.img-swap').click(function () {
  if($('a.img-swap.on').not(this).length) return;
  $(this).toggleClass('on');
 }); 
});
```

Comment: This works fine. Only problem is: I have to do also a check serverside. Because when clicking on a second anchor, the class doesn't switch anymore immediately, but it does after a refresh

Answer (score 0):

Try This -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.img-swap").click(function() {
    $("a.img-swap").each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass("on")) $(this).removeClass("on");
    });
    $(this).addClass("on");
  });
});
```

```css
.on {
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="img-swap on"> Img1 </a>

<a class="img-swap"> Img1 </a>

<a class="img-swap"> Img1 </a>

<a class="img-swap"> Img1 </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [`hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) to check if element has a class.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('a.img-swap').click(function () {
        if(!$("a.img-swap").hasClass("on"))
            $(this).toggleClass('on');
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('a.img-swap').click(function () {
       if($(".on").length > 0 ){
           console.log("Found");
       }else{
       console.log("not  found");
         $(this).addClass('on')
       }
       
     }); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='img-swap'>abcd1</a>
<a class='img-swap'>abcd2</a>
<a class='img-swap'>abcd3</a>
<a class='img-swap'>abcd4</a>
<a class='img-swap'>abcd5</a>
<a class='img-swap'>abcd6</a>
```